# Move mailbox checklist from 2003 to 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, exchange-2010, exchange-migration

Does anyone have a checklist for what needs to be done when moving a 2003 mailbox to 2010?

I'm considering enabling circular logging, checking disk space, and possibly disabling AV to speed up the transfer.

Are there special things I need to consider for resource accounts, delegates, service mailboxes, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had to "consider" too much in the E2K3 to E2K7 / E2K10 migrations I've done, personally. I've basically just left things as-is and moved the mailboxes.

If you're moving a ton of data I suppose you might enable circular logging on the destination server-- gauge your free disk space and decide if that's something you need to do. I've found that my E2K10 servers are typically so much more I/O efficient than the E2K3 servers I'm migrating from that leaving antivirus enabled on the destination server makes no difference. On the source server you might see a speed improvement, but I have no specific metrics to report.

None of my Customers have had problems with resource accounts after migrations so I haven't done anything special (both in E2K3 to E2K3 migrations nad E2K3 to E2K7 / E2K10 migrations). All mailbox access is supposed to dereference the mailbox store through the `homeMDB` property of the Active Directory object so the physical storage location of the mailbox should be irrelevant (and it has been in my experience).

Answer (score 1):

Check through [this](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000234.htm) article and [this](http://milindn.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/rapid-transition-guide-from-exchange-2003-to-exchange-2010.pdf) one.